# .start_with? method not recognizing substring 'a'

Tags: ruby

I want to translate a string into pig latin. The rules are as following:

1. Valid words are two or more letters long.
2. If a word begins with a consonant (a letter other than `'a'`, `'e'`, `'i'`, `'o'`, or `'u'`), then that first letter is shifted to the end of the word.
3. Then add `'ay'`.

I managed to come up with the method:

```
 def translate(word)
      if word.size <= 2
         word
      elsif
          word.size > 2
         !word.start_with?('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
          x = word.reverse.chop.reverse
          x.insert(-1, word[0])
          x << "ay"
      else
          word << "ay"
      end
    end
```

However, my test does not pass for certain strings,

```
Test Passed: Value == "c"
Test Passed: Value == "pklqfay"
Test Passed: Value == "yykay"
Test Passed: Value == "fqhzcbjay"
Test Passed: Value == "ndnrzzrhgtay"
Test Passed: Value == "dsvjray"
Test Passed: Value == "qnrgdfay"
Test Passed: Value == "npfay"
Test Passed: Value == "ldyuqpewypay"
Test Passed: Value == "arqokudmuxay"
Test Passed: Value == "spvhxay"
Test Passed: Value == "firvmanxay"
Expected: 'aeijezpbay' - Expected: "aeijezpbay", instead got: "eijezpbaay"
Expected: 'etafhuay' - Expected: "etafhuay", instead got: "tafhueay"
```

These tests passes:

```
Test.assert_equals(translate("billy"),"illybay","Expected: 'illybay'")
Test.assert_equals(translate("emily"),"emilyay","Expected: 'emilyay'")
```

I am not sure why.

Comment: I am using codewars so it is automatic.

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/all-star-code-challenge-number-13/train/ruby

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the length of `word` is greather or equal to 2 return word, if not then do the `start_with` step, but when would your `else` statement work?

Try modifying your length validation just to less than 2, then check if the word "start_with" a vowel, and return just the word plus `ay`, and if not the do the first character rotate step then adding the `ay` part, something like:

```
def translate(word)
  if word.size < 2
    word
  elsif word.start_with?('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    word << "ay"
  else
    x = word.reverse.chop.reverse
    x.insert(-1, word[0])
    x << "ay"
  end
end
```

Comment: I understand now that I over complicated my method! All my tests have gone green as well so thank you for correcting me Sebastian!

Comment: Good catch in `word.size < 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails because it doesn't really evaluates if the word begins with a constant, you are only checking it but doing nothing about it, its just an isolated line:

```
!word.start_with?('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

Try including that line **inside** an `if` condition, like this:

```
def translate(word)
  if word.size <= 2
    word
  else
    if !word.start_with?('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
      x = word.reverse.chop.reverse
      x.insert(-1, word[0])
      x << "ay"
    else
      word << "ay"
    end
  end
end
```

Also notice that i removed the `if word.size > 2`, it is not necessary since you are already checking for `word.size <= 2`, so anything other than that is `> 2`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and advice. Unfortunately one of the tests are still failing.

Comment: @Benjamints Which test?

Comment: Expected: 'efay' - Expected: "efay", instead got: "ef"

Comment: @Benjamints That's odd, it should output `efayay`, check it in action [here](https://repl.it/J9Jo). And the output `efay` doesn't match the initial conditions (i.e. _3. Then add "ay").

Comment: I know it is strange. I have been using repl.it all day and it was working just fine on that.

Comment: However, sebastian's code below passed for codewars. Still trying to understand why.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time though.

Comment: @Benjamints I see my error now: The provided word was not `efay` (as i understood), it was `ef` and should output `efay`; so when checking `word.size <= 2` the word `ef` is `= 2`, so it just returned it without any processing. Sebastian did noticed that problem and fixed to be `word.size < 2`.

Comment: Ahh okay. Thanks!